# How can I get an array of every point on a Line with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a line, with points at `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`.
What I need is a method that will just return every point in between them, in increments of whole numbers.

For example, a line going from `(0, 20)` to `(0, 40)` would give me `[(0, 20), (0, 21), (0, 22), ..., (0, 39), (0, 40))`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: (if necessary, I’m using a javafx.scene.shape.Line object here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Line` is horizontal or vertical and has `int` coordinates, you can use `IntStream`:

```
public static int[][] getPoints(Line line) {

    int startX = (int) Math.round(line.getStartX());
    int endX = (int) Math.round(line.getEndX());

    int startY = (int) Math.round(line.getStartY());
    int endY = (int) Math.round(line.getEndY());
    
    if (startX != endX && startY != endY) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Line must be horizontal or vetical");
    }
    
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(startX, endX).boxed()
        .flatMap(x -> IntStream.rangeClosed(startY, endY)
                .mapToObj(y -> new int[]{x, y})).toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Then:

```
Line line = new Line(0, 20, 0, 40);

int[][] points = getPoints(line);
    
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(points));
```

Output:

```
[[0, 20], [0, 21], [0, 22], [0, 23], [0, 24], [0, 25], [0, 26], [0, 27], [0, 28], [0, 29], [0, 30], [0, 31], [0, 32], [0, 33], [0, 34], [0, 35], [0, 36], [0, 37], [0, 38], [0, 39], [0, 40]]
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: @user16320675 that's correct, forgot to mention that restriction. I modified the answer to make that clear. Thanks for noticing.